# events.register is auto-executing the event being registered

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openstreetmap

I am trying to attach a Popup for each marker (I am using OpenLayers and OpenStreetMaps for this). Each marker is being registered an event 'click' that will show it's corresponding popup.

However, what it does is to just execute all the popups upon start-up instead of waiting for a given marker click.

There are approximately 1000 markers so I am using this loop to populate the markers and popups (which are hidden when created):

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
                {

                    if (i == 1) {

                        var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(data[i].Lon, data[i].Lat).transform(fromProjection, toProjection);
                        var zoom = 5;
                        map.setCenter(lonLat, zoom);
                    }

                    var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(data[i].Lon, data[i].Lat).transform(fromProjection, toProjection);
                    AddingPopup(lonLat);
                    AddingMarker(i, lonLat);
```

And these are my functions for creating both:

```
function AddingMarker(i, lonLat) {

    var marker = new OpenLayers.Marker(lonLat);

    markers.addMarker(marker);
    marker.events.register('click', marker, PopupsShow(i));
};

function AddingPopup(lonLat) {

    var popup = new OpenLayers.Popup("Popup", lonLat, null, "text", true);

    map.addPopup(popup);
    popup.hide();
};
```

And this is the function that is being auto-fired for all markers upon execution:

```
function PopupsShow(i) {

    map.popups[i].show();
};
```

What am I missing here. Why is the PopupsShow function started upon execution and it's not waiting for the marker to be clicked. I've been looking around for answers, but nothing seems to help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out:

We cannot register an event using `marker.events.register("click", marker, PopupsShow(i))`

Instead we need to call it like this: `marker.events.register("click", marker, PopupsShow)`

And since we need the `i` we can call it like this:

```
marker.events.register("click", marker, function () {
        map.popups[i].show();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The event handler can actually get an argument (event) which is the idiomatic way of performing this.  Also it is considered best to bind the handler to a layer instead of each marker.

```
markerLayer.events.register('click', marker,
      function(event) {
          var feature = event.feature;
          /* make popup appear */
  });
```

The way to make a popup varies to meet your needs, but usually the popup is created on demand here rather than pregenerating and calling show.